# How to check whether table is empty or not in android?

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I want to add data to the table called allquestions but have to check whether it is null or it contains any data.When I add data,it gets added every time i run the application.I want to clear the previous data every time I start the application.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allquestions (num_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, questions TEXT NOT NULL,catogery TEXT NOT NULL)" );
```

How to check whether the table contains any data?I want to add data if it does not contain any data.

Comment: You can perform a simple SELECT and then use `getCount()` from you `Cursor`. However, if you always need to delete data at start, it doesn't metter if the table if empty or not: just delete all its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();        
String query = "SELECT * FROM allquestions";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int count = cursor.getCount();
cursor.close();
return count
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something with the Cursor that gets returned by querying against the database, this is what you can do:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM allquestions", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
 \\Do something with the first row.
} else {
  \\There is nothing in the table.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a bit simpler than "requesting a record-count that you don't need."  And, if the OP is to "create the table if it doesn't exist, then delete everything that's in it," then, as others have said, you need only run the two queries back-to-back:  CREATE, then DELETE.  "If you don't need to care (if it's non-empty), you don't need to bother to find out."